# Map in ActiveMQ ObjectMessage throws ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-messaging

I'm using JMS `ObjectMessage` with ActiveMQ to transfer serializable POJOs in their `setObject()` function.

On my client:

```java
ObjectMessage omsg = getSession().createObjectMessage();
omsg.setObject(objectToSend);
```

The `objectToSend` is a POJO containing a `Map`:

```java
private Map<Integer, Double> tickIdToPrice;
```

On my server I try to decode:

```java
if (omsg.getObject() instanceof AJavaClass) {
```

But this causes an `Exception`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer 
    to field com.x.z.y.RequestPriceResult.tickIdToPrice of type 
    java.util.Map in instance of com.x.z.y.RequestPriceResult
```

Anyone know what is causing this exception? There is little to be found regarding `CollSer`.

Comment: I would discourage you from using `ObjectMessage` if at all possible. `ObjectMessage` depends on Java serialization to (un)marshal the payload which is generally considered unsafe because malicious payloads can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this. There are also a number of other issues not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/). This article has a good suggestion for how to replace `ObjectMessage` using JSON, etc.

Comment: Aside from the architectural and security issues with`ObjectMessage` it's worth noting that Java serialization is also *slow*.

Comment: Cheers @JustinBertram , doesn't the SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES setting solve most serialize security problems? I am currently using DTO's as objectmessage and really still like the easiness of java serialization. I might move to protobuff as payload as the project becomes more mature.

Comment: Whitelisting the packages allowed for deserialization helps reduce the security issues, but it doesn't necessarily eliminate them. And you still have the performance and architectural issues. Both ActiveMQ 5.x and [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) are multi-protocol brokers. By using `ObjectMessage` you're locking your clients down to Java & JMS. For example, you can't use STOMP from Python or AMQP from JavaScript or C#. Maybe you don't need this flexiblity now, but you might in the future. Limiting yourself now without clear, significant benefits seems unwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

CollSet is defined as:

```
A unified serialization proxy class for the immutable collections.
```

On my client i used `Map.of` to create a Map. This created a immutable map which when serialized uses CollSer. This caused problems with activemq, using a normal mutable map serializes and works fine.

Comment: Technically this is a workaround to the problem. (Not really a solution). The problem has nothing to do with ActiveMQ. It has to do with Java serialization.