# ClassCastException when unserializing an immutable List: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer to field of type java.util.List

Tags: java

I have this exception while unserializing an object:

java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer to field a.b.c.BaseClass.aField of type java.util.List in instance of a.b.c.SubClass.

At serialization, the a.b.c.BaseClass.aField does contain a List that was created like this

```
return List.copyOf(originalList);
```

I have a “simple” workaround to fix the problem by changing the previous line to:

```
return originalList.
```

Note that the list may be shared by multiple instances of a.b.c.BaseClass.
Stack:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer to field a.b.c.BaseClass.aField of type java.util.List in instance of a.b.c.SubClass.
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2227)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2191)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1478)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2657)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2471)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2242)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1742)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
    …
```

If I break and debug at the exception point:

```
   private void setObjFieldValues(Object obj, Object[] vals, boolean dryRun) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        for (int i = numPrimFields; i < fields.length; i++) {
            long key = writeKeys[i];
            if (key == Unsafe.INVALID_FIELD_OFFSET) {
                continue;           // discard value
            }
            switch (typeCodes[i]) {
                case 'L', '[' -> {
                    Object val = vals[offsets[i]];
                    if (val != null &&
                        !types[i - numPrimFields].isInstance(val))
                    {
                        Field f = fields[i].getField();
                        throw new ClassCastException(
                            "cannot assign instance of " +
                            val.getClass().getName() + " to field " +
                            f.getDeclaringClass().getName() + "." +
                            f.getName() + " of type " +
                            f.getType().getName() + " in instance of " +
                            obj.getClass().getName());
                    }
                    if (!dryRun)
                        unsafe.putReference(obj, key, val);
                }
                default -> throw new InternalError();
            }
        }
    }
```

In my scenario,

- obj is an instance of a.b.c.SubClass
- vals has 26 elements of    which index 17 is a CollSer
- dryRun is true
- The “i” value is 20.
- typecode[i] is ‘L’
- numPrimFields is 3
- offset[i] is 17
- types[i - numPrimFields] is java.util.List
- val is a CollSer    (array null, tag 1 (IMM_LIST))

The line:

```
!types[i - numPrimFields].isInstance(val)
```

Fails because java.util.List is not an instance of java.util.CollSer
I think (not sure) CollSer should probably have already been replaced by a List by CollSer’s readResolve.

Am I doing something wrong?

Unfortunately, this is a huge object being serialized (215 classes, 900MB on disk, error stack trace is 4200 lines) so I can’t easily reproduce the error using a simple test.
My env:

- openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-2724)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-2724, mixed mode, sharing)

(tested with version "20" also)

This question is probably a duplicate of [Map in ActiveMQ ObjectMessage throws ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.util.CollSer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65613929/731548)
that has been flagged as answered without a real solution.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=8304814

I think the problem is more specifically centered on the serialization of java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12.